# Adding Constraint with multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010

I have a SQL database opened with visual studio, and I need to add some constraints to a table already created. I need a foreign key, which already has a foreign key from a third table. To explain better ,

Table `ANIMALI` needs a foreign key from table `GABBIA`, which has already a foreign key from table `STANZA`. This was the code I came up with:

```
ALTER TABLE ANIMALE ADD CONSTRAINT REF_ANIMA_GABBI_FK FOREIGN KEY (n_stanza, n_gabbia) REFERENCES GABBIA(n_stanza, n_gabbia);
```

This gives me an error, `n_stanza is a column id not valid`. I think it's about the fact that the ID for the class `GABBIA` is taken from joining n_gabbia and n_stanza, the latter being a key in class `STANZA`.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your ALTER TABLE statement to work as written, both tables (not *classes*) "ANIMALE" and "GABBIA" must include the columns "n_stanza" and "n_gabbia".

In addition, in the table "GABBIA", there must be either a primary key constraint or a unique constraint on the pair of columns "n_stanza" and "n_gabbia".  That is, you need something like either `primary key (n_stanza, n_gabbia)` or `unique (n_stanza, n_gabbia)` in the table "GABBIA".